# Java enum value fields not accessible outside of definition

Tags: java, enums

In the following code the member fields of the `Colours` enum `GREEN` value are not accessible outside of the enum definition:

```
public class Test {

    enum Colours {
        RED,
        GREEN {
            public static final int hex = 0x00ff00;
            public final int hex2 = 0x00ff00;  // Try it without static, just in case...

            void f() {
                System.out.println(hex);    // OK
                System.out.println(hex2);   // OK
            }
        },
        BLUE
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Colours.GREEN.hex);      // COMPILE ERROR
        System.out.println(Colours.GREEN.hex2);     // COMPILE ERROR
    }
}
```

The offending lines give rise to the following compiler error:

```
Error:(38, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable hex
  location: variable GREEN of type Test.Colours
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? I assume the Java standard forbids it, but why?

Comment: *I assume the Java standard forbids it, but why?* - Because all enum values are of type `Colours`, which doesn't have those properties.

Comment: Note that `Colours.GREEN.f()` does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JLS §8.9.1. Enum Constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) an `enum` constant body is governed by the rules applicable to anonymous class, which restrict the accessibility of fields and methods:

> The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately enclosing enum type. The class body is governed by the usual rules of anonymous classes; in particular it cannot contain any constructors. Instance methods declared in these class bodies may be invoked outside the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible methods in the enclosing enum type (§8.4.8).

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I guess that makes sense. GREEN et al are objects which are either direct instances of Colours, or instances of an anonymous sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Colours {
    RED,
    GREEN {
        public static final int hex = 0x00ff00;
        public final int hex2 = 0x00ff00;  // Try it without static, just in case...

        void f() {
            System.out.println(hex);    // OK
            System.out.println(hex2);   // OK
        }
    },
    BLUE
}
```

Here, both `RED`, `GREEN` and `BLUE` are of type `Colours`, which doesn't know about `hex`, `hex2` or `f`, that's why your code doesn't compile.

What you can do is move them in the enum definition:

```
enum Colours {
    RED(0xff0000, 0xff0000),
    GREEN(0x00ff00, 0x00ff00),
    BLUE(0x0000ff, 0x0000ff);

    final int hex;
    final int hex2; 

    Colours(int hex, int hex2) {
        this.hex = hex;
        this.hex2 = hex2;
    }

    void f() {
        System.out.println(hex);    // OK
        System.out.println(hex2);   // OK
    }
}
```

This way all of these will compile:

```
System.out.println(Colours.GREEN.hex);
System.out.println(Colours.GREEN.hex2);
Colours.GREEN.f();
```

Comment: My example is not ideal. The static values in question are only relevant to one enum value.

Comment: @jon-hanson I understood that, but you can't. It's like that not just for enums: declaring `File f = new File("/path/to/file") { public int myField = 12; };` won't make you able to call `f.myField`, and it's like that by language definition ([§15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)). Also, enums can't be extended, so what you want to do is impossible.